# jsperf alternative that works on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, benchmarking, jsperf

I have been trying to use `jsperf.com` to test some code from jquery and ext js.  It works wonderfully in firefox and in chrome, but a lot of it won't work in internet explorer. Does anyone know any alternatives to jsperf that works well with IE?

Try this [example](http://jsperf.com/panels/16) in chrome, firefox, and IE. It works well in chrome and firefox, but once I try it in IE, it gives me an error.  What confuses me even more is that I'm able to open it in IE by itself, but not through jsperf.

Answer (score 10):

I’m the creator of [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/).

jsPerf was made to work in a wide variety of browsers and devices. If your test case doesn’t work in IE for some reason, it doesn’t mean jsPerf is broken — there’s probably something wrong with your test case.

Your test case is throwing “`jQuery` is undefined” errors. I’m guessing it’s because of this:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/chubicle/Javascript-Framework-Benchmarking/master/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.github.com/chubicle/Javascript-Framework-Benchmarking/master/easyui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You should probably include `jquery.easyui.min.js` *after* `jquery.min.js`, not the other way around.

**Update:** I’ve edited the test case for you and now it works fine.

Comment: @Raynos Hmm, everything seems to work fine for me in IE9. Could you please file a bug here, including links of broken pages? https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsperf.com/issues/new

Comment: Oh you're the creator, in that case, ur site is broken. I can't get it to work in Chrome, IE10, or FF on 3 different machines. Pretty sure it's not me

Comment: @SpYk3HH See previous comment. File a ticket explaining the problem in more detail.

Comment: Hey what happened to jsperf?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum  what happened indeed